# Vertx and Swagger project

Tags: vert.x

iam planning to use https://vertx.io/blog/presentation-of-the-vert-x-swagger-project/ to generate my project using swagger file.

Could you please let me know it is supported by the vertx community?

Answer (score 0):

This project is abandoned. Starting from vert.x 3.4, there is an official package called [vertx-web-api-contract](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-api-contract/java/) that supports OpenAPI 3 (the evolution of Swagger 2). It doesn't include a generator but it validates the requests. There is a project coming soon that also pushes to event bus the requests incoming to vert.x web router. If you need to convert your api definition from swagger 2 to openapi 3 use [mermade's openapi converter](https://mermade.org.uk/openapi-converter).

If you want a generator that scaffolds the project give a try to https://vertx-starter.jetdrone.xyz/